# Ultra Deep Field 3D camera speed

Tags: universe, speed, estimation

I guess most of you saw [Ultra Deep Field 3D](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAVjF_7ensg) video. In the end it shows camera moving in 3D perspective through all the galaxies. My question is, how fast is the camera moving in that video? I couldn't find this answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Deep Astronomy webpage](http://hubblesite.org/explore_astronomy/deep_astronomy/episodes/4) on the HUDF 3D,

> These galaxies, while standing absolutely still, are racing away from us, in some cases faster than the speed of light.  The spacetime between us and everything else grows larger by the minute, pushing the galaxies in this image to a distance of over 47 billion light years.

So if the image is 47 billion light years ($\sim10^{23}$ km) and it takes about 67 seconds for the video to zoom through that distance, then
$$
v_{video}=\frac{4.45\times10^{23}\,{\rm km}}{67\,{\rm s}}=6.64\times10^{21}{\rm km/s}=2.21\times10^{11}\,c
$$
So very, very fast.

Comment: I don't think the camera is zooming through the whole distance between Earth and the HUDF galaxies. They seem to be starting at the border of HUDF that is closer to Earth, but still extremely far away from the Earth. So the distance travelled by the camera should be the radial "thickness" of the group of the HUDF galaxies.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, and yes, mpv seems to be right, they start at the boarder of the image which is already zoomed in a lot.

Comment: @mpv: As far as I know, the closest HUDF galaxy is something like a billion or so light years away. Changing 47 Gly to 46 Gly will not change the superluminal results.